# Advantages of auto in template parameters in C++17

Tags: c++, templates, auto, c++17

What are the advantages of `auto` in template parameters that will (possibly) be introduced with C++17?

Is it just a natural extension of `auto` when I want to instantiate template code?

```
auto v1 = constant<5>;      // v1 == 5, decltype(v1) is int
auto v2 = constant<true>;   // v2 == true, decltype(v2) is bool
auto v3 = constant<'a'>;    // v3 == 'a', decltype(v3) is char
```

What else do I gain from this language feature?

Comment: As additional Information [Declaring non-type template arguments with auto](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r1.html)

Comment: Every now and then I see questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185315/passing-any-function-as-template-parameter) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232082/how-to-make-template-parameter) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049706/passing-pointer-to-any-member-function-as-class-template-argument) on StackOverflow. `template < auto >` will make these askers happy.

Comment: I thought the main thins was `std::vector<auto> v{1,2,3,4,5};` and difficult things like callable types as template args (esp lambdas).

Comment: @emsr: No, that's not what it does. The `auto` goes on the definition, not the point of use.

Comment: @emsr that's a separate feature that's part of the Concepts TS, but not in C++17. The p0127 use of `auto` does not conflict with it though.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The `template <auto>` feature ([P0127R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r1.html)) was accepted into C++ in the ISO C++ 2016 meeting in Oulu, Finland.

An `auto` keyword in a template parameter can be used to indicate a non-type parameter the type of which is deduced at the point of instantiation. It helps to think of this as a more convenient way of writing:

```
template <typename Type, Type value>
```

For example,

```
template <typename Type, Type value> constexpr Type constant = value;
constexpr auto const IntConstant42 = constant<int, 42>;
```

can now be written as

```
template <auto value> constexpr auto constant = value;
constexpr auto const IntConstant42 = constant<42>;
```

where you don't need to explicitly spell out the type any more. [P0127R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r1.html) also includes some simple but good examples where using `template <auto>` with variadic template parameters is very handy, for example for implementations of compile-time lists constant values:

```
template <auto ... vs> struct HeterogenousValueList {};
using MyList1 = HeterogenousValueList<42, 'X', 13u>;

template <auto v0, decltype(v0) ... vs> struct HomogenousValueList {};
using MyList2 = HomogenousValueList<1, 2, 3>;
```

In pre-C++1z, while `HomogenousValueList` could be simply written as

```
template <typename T, T ... vs> struct Cxx14HomogenousValueList {};
using MyList3 = Cxx14HomogenousValueList<int, 1, 2, 3>;
```

writing an equivalent of `HeterogenousValueList` would not be possible without wrapping the values in some other templates, for example:

```
template <typename ... ValueTypes> struct Cxx14HeterogenousValueList {};
using MyList4 = Cxx14HeterogenousValueList<constant<int, 42>,
                                           constant<char, 'X'> >;
```

Comment: non-type template parameters can't be anything so something like constant<3.0> doesn't work. So much for generic code.

Comment: @jondoe One potential workaround would be to use `std::ratio` in place of floating-point values and convert them to actual floating-point values later when needed.

Comment: @jondoe: C++20 does allow floating-point template parameters.

Comment: In your last example `constant` is a value, thus it cannot be passed to a `typename`.

Answer (score 15):

Actually, the case of real values in mceo's (original) answer is explicitly not covered as non-type template parameter.

```
template <auto ... vs> struct HeterogenousValueList {};
using MyList1 = HeterogenousValueList<42, 'X', 1.3f>;
```

See the example given in the mentioned proposal:
Modify §14.3.2 paragraph 2:

```
template<auto n> struct B { /* ... */ };
B<5> b1;   // OK: template parameter type is int
B<'a'> b2; // OK: template parameter type is char
B<2.5> b3; // error: template parameter type cannot be double
```

Just stumbled over the same misconception myself a few days ago.

Comment: While this is nice to know, and upvoted, by now I don't see how it's relevant to the question. Nobody is now suggesting real values can be used as non-type template parameters.

Comment: This was an answer to the original answer of mceo, where he gave an example of a real value as template argument, which, however, is not permitted. This aspect is now included in the accepted answer above after being edited, and is now essentially redundant.

Comment: And it is relevant to the question in the sense that the introduction of 'auto' did not sneak in new template argument types as one can easily get the impression of.

Comment: FYI, in C++20, floating-point values are allowed as template parameters.  See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1714r1.html

Answer (score 7):

Here is another example (**originally presented by [@Rakete1111](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48608869/2085626)** as an answer for [template template parameter of unknown type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608830/template-template-parameter-of-unknown-type)):

### Extracting the value of SIZE without knowing its type:

```
template<std::size_t SIZE>
class Foo {};

template <template<auto> class T, auto K>
auto extractSize(const T<K>&) {
    return K;
}

int main() {
    Foo<6> f1;
    Foo<13> f2;
    std::cout << extractSize(f1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << extractSize(f2) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Concerning `C++17`, is `auto` in this context constrained to the set of types of a non-type template parameter?

Comment: Can you please explain how this works?

Comment: @AlexO We are captueing K as a template template parameter. Same as typename for template says "any type, compiler please deduce" the auto for the inner template parameter says "any type of value" which helps here as the inner template parameter is a non-type.

Answer (score 7):

### C++20 seemed to add another usage

... but it doesn't :-(

The [concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B)) technical specification allowed a function parameter with `auto` template argument placeholder, e.g.:

```
void printPair(const std::pair<auto, auto>& p) {
    std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << std::endl;
}
```

But it was removed later in the C++20 specification.

This is a neat usage...
**I am hoping it will get in again in C++26!**

See: *['auto' as a template argument placeholder for a function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60358154/auto-as-a-template-parameter-for-a-function-parameter)*

Comment: Yeah this simplifies a lot of boilerplate, i want this too. GCC compiles this, Clang refuses.