# inferring type of variadic template parameter pack element

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I have following function:

```
template <typename T, T... Ts> T random_value(default_random_engine &rnd)
{
    static constexpr T values [] { Ts... };
    static uniform_int_distribution<size_t> distribution(0, sizeof...(Ts) - 1);
    return values[distribution(rnd)];
}
```

That is called just so:

```
MyEnum val = random_value<MyEnum, MyEnum::val1, MyEnum::val2, MyEnum::val3>(rnd);
```

Is it possible to re-define it in such a way to I don't need to specify T explicitly? So that it is called just so:

```
MyEnum val = random_value<MyEnum::val1, MyEnum::val2, MyEnum::val3>(rnd);
```

Comment: you could use a macro with decltype obviously, but otherwise i think bryan is right

Comment: Sadly you cannot do it elegantly (or at all) in C++ (for the moment). Like Chris said the only way around this is with a macro: `#define RANDOM_VALUE(x,...)random_value<decltype(x),x,__VA_ARGS__>()`

Answer (score 5):

Not at this time, but the new `auto` template parameter feature being added in C++17 will help with this. See [Advantages of auto in template parameters in C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026884/advantages-of-auto-in-template-parameters-in-c17)