# C++ template array size deduction

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I'm trying to devise a way for the compiler to deduce the size of an array passed as a non-type template parameter.

I can make the template work if I explicitly pass the array size as a third template parameter, but that opens the technique to errors.

Can anyone think of a way of doing this.
The code below doesn't compile, but it gives an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
// Compile time deduction of array size.
template <typename T, const size_t SIZE>
char(&array_size(T(&array)[SIZE]))[SIZE];

#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) (sizeof(array_size(x)))

template <typename T, T BEGIN[]>
struct Test
{
  enum
  {
    SIZE = ARRAY_SIZE(BEGIN)
  };
};

int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

int main()
{
  Test<int, a> test;

  return 0;
}
```

[EDIT]
I forgot to point out that the solution must also be C++03 compatible.

Comment: Look to `std::array` for inspiration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Template Parameter with implicit array size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241440/template-parameter-with-implicit-array-size/48241786#48241786)

Answer (score 5):

Simply

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t array_size(const T(&)[N]) { return N; }
```

In C++17, you may do

```
template <auto V>
struct Test
{
    enum { SIZE = array_size(*V) };
};
```

and

```
Test<&a> test;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf0980d918f83ce1)

Before, you may do a more verbose

```
template <typename T, T t>
struct Test
{
    enum { SIZE = array_size(*t) };
};
```

and

```
Test<decltype(&a), &a> test;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1571124811d7980) (works with gcc but not clang :-/)

Version which also works with clang:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> array_size(const T(&)[N]) { return {}; }

template <typename T, T V>
struct Test
{
    enum { SIZE = decltype(array_size(*std::declval<T>()))::value };
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da6ade5197138cc1)

Comment: Doesn't compile. "error C2101: '&' on constant" for enum { SIZE = array_size(*t) };

Comment: For C++17 version. "a parameter cannot have a type that contains 'auto'"

Comment: Note: I tried compiling with the C++ standard set to C++17

Comment: @JWellbelove: I added a demo link which works (I had a case typo) on gcc (but not on clang...). Which compiler do you use ?

Comment: Work-around found for clang too.

Answer (score -1):

C++11 introduced extent in type_traits

```
#include <type_traits>
std::extent<decltype(a)>::value
```

which evaluates to the array size of the template argument.
See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent

Comment: The SIZE is always defined as zero when I use this inside the template class.