# Deduce/erase type of template template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-templates

When using *template template* arguments how can I have the template type of the *template template* deduced or erased?

Consider the following SSCCE:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int i>
struct Value { };

template<int i>
struct BadValue { };

template<typename... G>
struct Print;

template<template<int> class ValueType, int... Is>
struct Print< ValueType<Is>... > {
    static void print() {
        const int is[] = { Is... };
        for (int i: is)
            cout << i;
        cout << endl;
    }

};

using V1 = Value<1>;
using V2 = Value<2>;
using V3 = Value<3>;
using BV = BadValue<1>;

int main() {
    Print<V2, V1, V2, V3>::print(); // <-- fine
    Print<V2, V1, V2, BV>::print(); // <-- BV used by accident
}
```

Deducing the `template<int> class ValueType` argument of the `Print` class  to a template class like the `Value` and `BadValue` classes enforces that all the template arguments in the parameter pack to the `Print` class are specializations of the same `ValueType` template class - this is intentional. That is, the second line in the `main()` function causes a compile-time error as the `ValueType` argument cannot be deduced to match both the `Value` and `BadValue` classes. If the user by accident tries to mix the templates when using the `Print` template a compile time error arises, which provides a bit of diagnostic.

The above implementation, however, still has the `int` type fixed for the inner template argument of the `ValueType` template template argument. How can I erase it and have it deduced as well?

Generally speaking, when deducing a *template template* argument, how can I access the *inner* template argument?

Comment: It seems there is a typo in your code: `VB` -> `BV`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want that `Print<V2, V1, V2, VB>::print();` generate an error that is simpler to understand.

For this, the best I can imagine is to works with `static_assert()`s.

In this particular case -- `Print` is a `struct` with only a partial specialization implemented and no general version implemented -- a not really but simple solution is available: implement the general version to give a `static_assert()` error with a message of your choice.

By example

```
template <typename ... G>
struct Print
 {
   static_assert( sizeof...(G) == 0, "not same int container for Print<>");

   static void print()
    { };
 };

template <template<int> class ValueType, int ... Is>
struct Print< ValueType<Is>... >
 {
   static void print()
    {
      using unused = int const [];

      (void)unused { (std::cout << Is, 0)... };

      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
 };
```

Unfortunately this solution accept as valid `Print<>`; I don't know if is good for you.

Another (better, IMHO, but more elaborate) solution can be transform the `Print` partial specialization in a specialization that accept variadic `int` containers (variadic `ValueTypes` instead a fixed `ValueType`) and, in a `static_assert()`, check (with a custom type traits) that all containers are the same.

Bye example, with the following custom type traits

```
template <template <int> class ...>
struct sameCnts : public std::false_type
 { };

template <template <int> class C0>
struct sameCnts<C0> : public std::true_type
 { };

template <template <int> class C0, template <int> class ... Cs>
struct sameCnts<C0, C0, Cs...> : public sameCnts<C0, Cs...>
 { };
```

you can write the `Print` specialization as follows

```
template <template <int> class ... Cs, int ... Is>
struct Print< Cs<Is>... >
 {
   static_assert(sameCnts<Cs...>{}, "different containers in Print<>");

   static void print()
    {
      using unused = int const [];

      (void)unused { (std::cout << Is, 0)... };

      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
 };
```

If you can use C++17, you can use folding and the type traits can be written

```
template <template <int> class, template <int> class>
struct sameCnt : public std::false_type
 { };

template <template <int> class C>
struct sameCnt<C, C> : public std::true_type
 { };

template <template <int> class C0, template <int> class ... Cs>
struct sameCnts
   : public std::bool_constant<(sameCnt<C0, Cs>::value && ...)>
 { };
```

and (using folding also in `print()` method) `Print` as follows

```
template <template <int> class ... Cs, int ... Is>
struct Print< Cs<Is>... >
 {
   static_assert( sameCnts<Cs...>{}, "different containers in Print<>");

   static void print()
    { (std::cout << ... << Is) << std::endl; }
 };
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask

> But how can I have the Print class accept also, for example, types that are specialized for a double non-type value instead of the int non-type values?

Not sure to understand what do you want but (remembering that a `double` value can't be a template non-type parameter) I suppose you want a `Print` that accept types with non-types template parameter when the type of this non type template parameter isn't fixed as in your example (`int`).

For C++11 and C++14 I think that in necessary to explicit the type of the non type values.

I mean... If you write `Print` as follows

```
template <typename ...>
struct Print;

template <typename T, template <T> class ... Cs, T ... Is>
struct Print< T, Cs<Is>... >
 {
   static_assert(sameCnts<Cs...>{}, "different containers in Print<>");

   // ...
 };
```

you have to use it this way

```
Print<int, V2, V1, V2, V3>::print();
```

that is explicating `int` (or `long`, or whatever) as first template parameter. This because the `int` type can't be deduced.

Starting from C++17 you can use `auto` as type for non-type template parameter, so you can write `Print` as follows

```
template <typename ...>
struct Print;

template <template <auto> class ... Cs, auto ... Is>
struct Print< Cs<Is>... >
 {
   static_assert( sameCnts<Cs...>{}, "different containers in Print<>");

   static void print()
    { (std::cout << ... << Is) << std::endl; }
 };
```

and the is no need to explicit the type and you can write

```
Print<V2, V1, V2, V3>::print();
```

In this case, you have to use `auto` instead of `int` also in `sameCnt` and `sameCnts`.

Comment: Maybe it would be good to explain what was going wrong in the original post: That without the variadic template template parameter it was being deduced as two conflicting templates.

Comment: @TimSeguine - I've tried to explain this but I'm not good with words... I'll try to explain better.

Comment: Actually, I exactly WANT it to go wrong with conflicting templates. I suppose my wording wasn't that clear either :-) The problem is I want to have the `int` deduced.

Comment: @Kamajii - ehmm... yes, I'm really confused now; do you want an error but do you want the `int` deduced? Suggestion: explain what do you exactly want, with examples, but do it modifying the question (so other readers can notice it).

Comment: Yes, exactly. The `Print` template should enforce that all its template arguments have the same (template) type. This is why I don't want the template itself be part of the parameter pack.

Comment: @Kamajii - so what's wrong with the error in your original code?

Comment: Aaaaahhhhh. I'm sorry. Nothing is wrong with it, it is _intended_ - amended!

Comment: @Kamajii - sorry but I don't understand what do you want obtain; please, can you modify your question to explain it?

Comment: @Kamajii - so do you want the error but only a better diagnostic? Another doubt:  do you want to accept `ValueType`s different than `Value`; in other words: `Print<BV, BV, BV>::print();` should compile or should give an error (with better diagnostic)?

Comment: @Kamajii - answer modified in the case you want accept valid `Print<BV, BV, BV>::print()`

Comment: I like the way you implemented the diagnostics. But how can I have the `Print` class accept also, for example, types that are specialized for a `double` non-type value instead of the `int` non-type values?

Comment: @Kamanji - uhmmm... a `double` can't be a non-type template value; anyway, do you mean that the `int` in `template<int> class ValueType` should be a template parameter?

Comment: @max66: Yes, of course - with `double` non-type value I mean concrete instances of `double`, i.e. numbers. It is a little frustrating that my English capabilities don't seem to suffice to get the wording unambiguous. I probably need to sort my vocabulary and coin the correct terms :-/

Comment: @Kamajii - the frustrating part (for me) is that my English capabilities are worse than yours. Anyway... answer improved; hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you work in C++17, you can [declare non-type template parameter with `auto`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026884/advantages-of-auto-in-template-parameters-in-c17), so simply declare `Is` as `auto...`, and use `auto` instead of `int` in the function definition as possible as you can.

Of course, since type of elements of `Is` may be different, it may be impossible to declare the array `is`. Instead, you can use `std::tuple` and [print the tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6894436/5376789) instead.

```
// print_tuple is used to print a tuple

template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Tp)>::type
  print_tuple(const std::tuple<Tp...>&)
  { }

template<std::size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
inline typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Tp)>::type
  print_tuple(const std::tuple<Tp...>& t)
  {
    std::cout << std::get<I>(t);  
    print_tuple<I + 1, Tp...>(t);
  }

// ...

template<template<int> class ValueType, auto... Is>
                                     // ^^^^
struct Print< ValueType<Is>... > {
    static void print() {
        print_tuple(std::make_tuple(Is...)); // make a tuple, and print it
    }
};
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5QLCdJjeKVhvPOlM)

The above pattern (making a tuple then dealing with the tuple) allows you to apply some complicated function to the parameter pack `Is`. However, if you only want to print the pack, you can alternatively use the C++17 feature [fold expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) instead, which is simpler.

```
template<template<int> class ValueType, auto... Is>
                                     // ^^^^
struct Print< ValueType<Is>... > {
    static void print() {
        (std::cout << ... << Is); // fold expression, also C++17 feature
    }
};
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/V0PKJSeyZ10Xxbyk)

Comment: So the type given in the nested `template<>` does not matter, actually?

Comment: @Kamajii Yes, is that intended? I have also updated the answer to add more details.