# Dispatch template <auto>

Tags: c++, c++17

I try to dispatch between two functions using `if constexpr`. The dispatcher function should accept for example `std::size_t` and an arbitrary class type.

It works if I just call it with a scalar type, but if I try to pass a class type it triggers a compile error which is not really helpful to me (please see below).

Please have a look at my current approach:

```
template <auto Other>
constexpr auto mul() const {
  if constexpr (std::is_scalar_v<decltype(Other)>)
    return mul_with_scalar<Other>();
  else
    return mul_with_matrix<Other>();
}

template <size_t Scalar>
constexpr auto mul_with_scalar() const {
  return apply([](size_t v, auto) { return v * Scalar; },
               std::make_index_sequence<Size>{});
}

template <class Other>
constexpr auto mul_with_matrix() const {
  return size_t{0}; // implement me
}
```

```
note: candidate: template<auto Other> constexpr auto matrix<Rows, Cols, Vals>::mul() const [with auto Other = Other; long unsigned int Rows = 3; long unsigned int Cols = 3; long unsigned int ...Vals = {}]
   constexpr auto mul() const {
                  ^~~
./constexpresian/matrix.hpp:81:18: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

Comment: Is `Other` supposed to be a type or not?

Comment: I wan't that the function `mul` can handle non-type and type parameters. So `Other` can be both, I thought that is possible with `template <auto>`?

Comment: @Hamdor No, it's not possible. A template parameter cannot accept both types and values. You could just take any type and wrap values in a `std::integer_constant`, though.

Comment: what about `return mul_with_matrix<decltype(Other)>();` ?

Comment: In your 2nd template where is the value `Size` coming from in the `std::make_index_sequence<Size>{} );` line of code?

Comment: Tried that already, same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wan't that the function `mul` can handle non-type and type parameters.

That is not possible in C++. A template parameter can be a type or a value (or a template), but it cannot be both. `template<auto Name>` makes `Name` a value template parameter, the type of whose value will be deduced at the time the value is passed.

But since it is a compile-time value, you can wrap its value in a type. For integer types, `std::integer_constant` will work. For future C++ revisions that allow other kinds of value parameters, you'll have to use a more generic wrapper.

Comment: I thought that is one use case for `template <auto>`. But it seems thats wrong...

Answer (score 1):

There is one question I have, you can refer to my comment below your post that pertains to the term `Size`.

I tried your code above as is even with `Size` the way it is to see the compiler errors and this is coming from Visual Studio 2017 v4.6.0105 c++17 on Win 7 x64 Home Premium under x86 Debug on an Intel Quad Core Extreme.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: StackOverflow, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Learner.cpp
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\stackoverflow\stackoverflow\learner.h(75): error C3533: a parameter cannot have a type that contains 'auto'
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\stackoverflow\stackoverflow\learner.h(75): error C2270: 'mul': modifiers not allowed on nonmember functions
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\stackoverflow\stackoverflow\learner.h(83): error C2270: 'mul_with_scalar': modifiers not allowed on nonmember functions
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\stackoverflow\stackoverflow\learner.h(89): error C2270: 'mul_with_matrix': modifiers not allowed on nonmember functions
1>Done building project "StackOverflow.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Maybe this interpretation of these compiler errors might help you.

Here are some links that might help concerning `auto` and `template parameters`:

- [StackOverflow : Advantages of auto in template parameters in C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026884/advantages-of-auto-in-template-parameters-in-c17)
- [open-std.org : Declaring non-type template arguments with auto](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r1.html)
- [www.bfilipek.com : C++17 in details: Templates](http://www.bfilipek.com/2017/06/cpp17-details-templates.html)