# Extract data from heterogeneous list

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17

I was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38044251/68304) about the [advantages of auto in template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026884/advantages-of-auto-in-template-parameters-in-c17).

Please consider the following heterogeneous list:

```
template <auto ... vs> struct HeterogenousValueList {};
using MyList1 = HeterogenousValueList<42, 'X', 13u>;
```

Now I've declared a type named `MyList1`. How can I extract the stored data from this type (i.e., 42, 'x' or 13u)?

Comment: Depends on what do you want to do with that data. To pass it around, you can just use `vs` just like any other non-type variadic pack. You can expand it into some (possibly) variadic function with `vs...` and then proceed just like with a function, etc.

Comment: I think this question is too broad. Please specify a little bit more exactly what do you mean by "extract stored data". What do you want to do with `vs`? Print it? Pass it to some other function?

Comment: Just playing with this C++17 feature. Learning it by manipulation. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To extract data from a template parameter pack, we usually do pattern matching in template.

Firstly, we create a class template `At` but without contents. Its template parameters are supposed to be an index, and an instance of `HeterogenousValueList`. This class template will be used like a function to access information in the list.

```
template <int Index, class ValueList>
struct At;
```

Next, we create a specialization of `At`. This is where pattern matching is used. Through pattern matching, the first element of the list will become `u`. The rest of the list will be `vs`. If the index is `0`, `u` can be accessed through the static member `value`. Note that `vs` can be an empty list, so this also covers the case that `u` being the last of the list.

```
template <auto u, auto... vs>
struct At<0, HeterogenousValueList<u, vs...>>
{
    static constexpr auto value = u;
};
```

What if the index is not 0? We shift the list and decrement the index by 1, and pass them into `At` again. In other words, this is a template recursion.

```
template <int Index, auto u, auto... vs>
struct At<Index, HeterogenousValueList<u, vs...>>
{
    static constexpr auto value = At<Index - 1, HeterogenousValueList<vs...>>::value;
};
```

Now, we can try to use it: https://godbolt.org/g/51dpH8

```
int main()
{
    volatile auto value0 = At<0, MyList1>::value;
    volatile auto value1 = At<1, MyList1>::value;
    volatile auto value2 = At<2, MyList1>::value;
    // volatile auto value3 = At<-1, MyList1>::value;
    // volatile auto value4 = At<3, MyList1>::value;
}
```

I use volatile variable so that the compiler does not optimize the effect away and you can see the effect in the assembly listing.

And one more great thing: the compiler checks the bound! We usually don't have bound check for run-time array for run-time efficiency reason. But this is a compile-time list. The compiler can do it for us!

---

Actually, there is a simpler implementation. This time, we use constexpr-if in a function template. But the idea of pattern matching and template recursion remain the same.

```
template <int Index, auto u, auto... vs>
auto at(HeterogenousValueList<u, vs...>)
{
    if constexpr (Index == 0)
        return u;
    else
        return at<Index - 1>(HeterogenousValueList<vs...>{});
}
```

And this time, when we use it, we need to instantiate `MyList1` into an object.

https://godbolt.org/g/CA3VHj

```
int main()
{
    volatile auto value0 = at<0>(MyList1{});
    volatile auto value1 = at<1>(MyList1{});
    volatile auto value2 = at<2>(MyList1{});
    // volatile auto value3 = at<-1, MyList1>::value;
    // volatile auto value4 = at<3, MyList1>::value;
}
```

Comment: For convenience of your consumers, you might want to use `std::integral_constant` in your solution. And maybe also template-templates for generality.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention "playing" and "learning it by manipulation", you may be interested in several alternatives.

### First solution: convert to `std::tuple` and then `std::get`

The [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), which is a container for heterogeneous values, can be utilized to access the elements of your heterogeneous value list. This is a simple two-step process:

1. convert `HeterogenousValueList<42, 'X', 13u>{}` to `std::tuple<int, char, unsigned>{42, 'X', 13u}`
2. access the tuple's values at the desired positions by [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get)

Complete C++17 example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<auto... vs>
struct HeterogenousValueList {};

template<int i, auto... vs>
constexpr auto get(HeterogenousValueList<vs...>) {
  constexpr std::tuple tuple{vs...};// class-template argument deduction

  static_assert(std::is_same<
    decltype(tuple), const std::tuple<int, char, unsigned>
  >{});

  return std::get<i>(tuple);
}

int main() {
  using MyList1 = HeterogenousValueList<42, 'X', 13u>;

  constexpr auto at1 = get<1>(MyList1{});
  static_assert(at1 == 'X');
  static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(at1), const char>{});
}
```

### Second solution: wrap in types for `std::tuple_element_t`

Another useful idiom is to wrap non-type template parameters in a single empty type. In your example, this allows to make use of [`std::tuple_element_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element), which can yield the nth type of a variadic pack:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<auto... vs>
struct HeterogenousValueList {};

template<auto v_>
struct SingleValue {// similar to std::integral_constant, but uses auto
  static constexpr auto v = v_;
};

template<int i, auto... vs>
constexpr auto get(HeterogenousValueList<vs...>) {
  using TupleOfSingleValues = std::tuple<SingleValue<vs>...>;
  using SingleValueAtPosition = std::tuple_element_t<i, TupleOfSingleValues>;
  return SingleValueAtPosition::v;
//  return std::tuple_element_t<i, std::tuple<SingleValue<vs>...>>::v;// same
}

// same `main` as first solution
```

### Third solution: Implement your own logic

There are several ways to implement your own version for "getting the nth type/element". One aspect in this business is the compile-time performance: particularly the recursive strategies are said to cause long compilation times.

My favorite non-recursive strategy is the one [which is also used in Boost.Hana](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/master/include/boost/hana/detail/type_at.hpp). If you prefer a video explanation you can watch two minutes of the talk ["Metaprogramming for the brave" by Louis Dionne (Boost.Hana author) starting at 01 h 12 min](https://youtu.be/UXwWXHrvTug?t=1h12m1s). The idea is to use **multiple inheritance**. In your example, `HeterogenousList<42, 'X', 13u>` can have the base classes `IndexedValue<0, 42>`, `IndexedValue<1, 'X'>`, and `IndexedValue<2, 13u>`. Then you can pass the `HeterogenousList<42, 'X', 13u>` to a templated `get` function that takes a, say, `const IndexedValue<1, [[DEDUCED]]>&` as argument:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<std::size_t i, auto v_>
struct IndexedValue {
  static constexpr auto v = v_;
};

template<class Is, auto... vs>
struct IndexedHeterogenousList;

template<std::size_t... is, auto... vs>
struct IndexedHeterogenousList<
  std::index_sequence<is...>,// partial specialization to extract the `is`
  vs...
> : IndexedValue<is, vs>...// multiple "variadic" inheritance
{};

template<auto... vs>
struct HeterogenousValueList
  : IndexedHeterogenousList<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(vs)>, vs...>
{};

template<std::size_t i, auto v>// `i` must be given; `v` is deduced
constexpr auto get(const IndexedValue<i, v>& iv) {// one base matches
  return v;
}

// same `main` as first solution
```