# How can I deduce a template parameter type in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constexpr

I'm attempting to write a function that forces `constexpr` evaluation via. a template. I wrote this, but it works only for `int` (beware, will give recursion depth errors with GCC):

```
#include <iostream>

template<int val>
constexpr int force_constexpr() { return val; }

constexpr int triangle(int n)
{
    return n ? n + triangle(n - 1) : 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << force_constexpr<triangle(0x200)>() << '\n';
}
```

Note that this is for demonstration purposes only; I know that the triangle number can be calculated with `(n+1)*n/2`.

Then I attempted to write a generic function, however, that doesn't work as well. This is a plain error (not surprising, as it uses `T` before `T` is defined):

```
template<T val, typename T = decltype(val)>
constexpr T force_constexpr() { return val; }
```

as is this (which obviously won't work; it's a nested template):

```
template<typename T>
template<T val>
constexpr T force_constexpr() { return val; }
```

and this requires the type of the argument to be passed:

```
template<typename T, T val>
constexpr T force_constexpr() { return val; }
```

How can I do this without passing the type as a parameter to the template? Or, in other words, how can I deduce a template parameter type?

I'm looking for a C++11 solution but solutions for other standards are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `auto` template parameters, in C++17:

```
#include <iostream>

template<auto T>
auto *singleton()
{
    static const decltype(T) solo{T};

    return &solo;
}

int main()
{
    const int *p=singleton<42>();

    std::cout << "The meaning of life: " << *p << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Specify the template parameter as `auto`, and use `decltype` to deduce its type.

I do not believe that this is possible before C++17, since [this is precisely the use case for which `auto` template parameters were added to the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026884/advantages-of-auto-in-template-parameters-in-c17). Couldn't do this, conceptually, before then.

Answer (score 0):

C++17 introduces `auto` as non type template parameter:

```
template <auto val>
constexpr auto force_constexpr() { return val; }
```

Before, you have indeed blocked with

```
template<typename T, T val>
constexpr T force_constexpr() { return val; }
```

You can introduce MACRO to simplify usage:

```
#define AUTO(v) decltype(v), (v)
```

And then

```
std::cout << force_constexpr<AUTO(triangle(0x200))>() << '\n';
```