# deducing non-type template argument type from template function argument

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction, function-templates, non-type-template-parameter

I have a template function parametrized by a compile-time constant whose type should be the same as the type of the function argument.

For instance, I'm seeking to have this kind of syntax:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>

using mytype_t = std::uint8_t;
constexpr mytype_t Min = 0;

template <typename T, T limit>
bool GreaterThanLimit(T const x) {
    if constexpr (limit > std::numeric_limits<T>::min()) {
        return (limit <= x);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

int main() {
    mytype_t x = 42;
    // KO
    bool v = GreaterThanLimit<Min>(x);
    static_cast<void>(v);
}
```

[Non working Live](https://godbolt.org/z/orqjnoYPo)

This dummy function is taking some runtime value `x` and a compile-time constant, that I want to be of the same type as x (let say it is an integral type), and tells if `x` is greater or equal than its limit.

How can I achieve that (C++14 if possible, C++17 at most)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [auto template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38044251/16941344) in C++17, things will do:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

using mytype_t = std::uint8_t;
constexpr mytype_t Min = 0;

template <auto limit, typename T> bool GreaterThanLimit(T const x) {
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype<limit>,T>);

  if constexpr (limit > std::numeric_limits<T>::min()) {
    return (limit <= x);
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

int main() {
  int x = 42;

  // Works
  bool v = GreaterThanLimit<Min>(x);
  static_cast<void>(v);
}
```

```
❯ g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp -o test
❯ ./test
❯ echo $?
0
```

Comment: what deduction is specific to c++17?

Comment: do you mean `auto` template arguments that were introduced in c++17 ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai My bad, I mixed these two things up.

Comment: also OP asks for "function is taking some runtime value x and a compile-time constant, that I want to be of the same type as x " but you just take `Min` with whatever type it is and `x` with whatever type is passed in

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Updated, sincere appreciation

Comment: Sorry, I was editing the question as the C++17 answer was quite obvious in fact. You were faster, thus I leave my question untouched.
Yet I would be interested to know if there is a C++14 way to do that.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Since OP said he will put two things of the same type in the function, I can assume this won't need protection. I'll add a protection on it.

Comment: Annnnnnnnnnd @463035818_is_not_an_ai is right, it's not that obvious as the type constraint is not enforced.

Comment: @Oersted Would my update in `GreaterThanLimit` make sense?

Comment: @LiuYuan, I had something like that in mind and I think it is functionally acceptable. I have a doubt though about ```std::is_convertible```: it only guarantees that an implicit conversion exists, not that it keeps accuracy or that it won't overflow? I'll have to check what happen if I set a limit larger than the desired type max.

Comment: @Oersted Yeah, I think `std::is_convertible` will fail in some extreme cases. If so, we will need a stronger restrictions. Let me find out.

Comment: failure with overflow: https://godbolt.org/z/nTcPMeo7v. @LiuYuan, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @Oersted Don't give it up! I'm updating!

Comment: Thanks. By the way I think that you went above the expectation. I think that in my actual use case, a brutal ```static_assert(std::is_same<decltype<limit>,T>)``` would have done the job by forcing the user to explicitely cast to the right type.

Comment: @Oersted Exactly, this is the strictest limit. I think this will do.

Answer (score 3):

C++14 doesn't have `auto` as template parameter.

You might turn your template parameter into function argument:

```
template <typename T, T limit>
bool GreaterThanLimit(std::integral_constant<T, limit>, T x)
{
    return limit <= x;
}

using mytype_t = std::uint8_t;
constexpr std::integral_constant<mytype_t, 0> Min{};

int main() {
    mytype_t x = 42;
    [[maybe_unused]] bool v = GreaterThanLimit(Min, x);
}
```